# Realtime streaming video to HTML5 with RaspberryPi, gstreamer

Tags: raspbian, raspicam, streaming-video, html5

I'm trying to make a live stream from a Raspberry camera available on a HTML5 webpage.  Because of combination of factors, I would like to stream it to an outside server pc(Server pc os is window7) and and this server should be able to supply the streams to the webpage HTML.

I'm able to get the stream from the Raspberry Pi and stream it with Gstreamer to an external server like this:

Raspberry Pi:

```
raspivid -n -t 0 -rot 270 -w 960 -h 720 -fps 30 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 - e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph24pay pt=96 config-interval=1 ! udpsink host=External_IP port=5000
```

External server

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

As a result I could display live streaming video through gstreamer(GStreamer D3D video sink) in external server pc.

Now I have a problem:

I want to display this video through html in server pc's Apache server,
not program "GStreamer D3D video sink"

I found this solution for a long time but I couldn't find that.

please give me information of this problem :)
thanks!